# mingwでfilesystem::copy_file()を使用した際、overwrite_existingを指定していても上書きが出来ません

Tags: c++, mingw

例としては以下のコードとなります

```
#include <filesystem>
int main(){
    std::filesystem::copy_file("./t.txt","./test/t.txt",std::filesystem::copy_options::overwrite_existing);
}
```

./t.txt、./test共に存在しており、./test/t.txtのみ存在しない状態で2連続実行した所
1度目は成功し 2度目は例外が投げられました

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: cannot copy file: File exists [./t.txt] [./test/t.txt]
```

ライブラリ側のバグでしょうか？
それとも自分の誤認識(またはミス)による物でしょうか？

また、余談ではありますが
msvc(vs2019)、gcc(WSL(ubuntu18.04))では例外が投げられず、上書きが行われる事を確認しています

[環境]
・OS:windows10
・コンパイルオプション:両者ともに「-std=c++17」のみ
・コンパイラ
　g++(msys2:mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain)

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-9.3.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-isl-version-check --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --enable-plugin --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
```

clang++(msys2:mingw-w64-x86_64-clang)

```
clang version 9.0.1 (https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages.git 5e3b8820ed9f04221affee4197e458aca2612e87)
Target: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin
```

Comment: ファイル"./t.txt"のプロテクション()はどうなっていますか？
"./t.txt"が読み取り専用(書き込みができない)no

Answer (score 1):

ファイル"./t.txt"のプロテクションはどうなっていますか？

"./t.txt"が読み取り専用(書き込みができない)のファイルだと、それがコピーされた"./test/t.txt"も読み取り専用になります。

１回目の実行で、読み取り専用の"./test/t.txt"が作られて、２回目の実行で読み取り専用の"./test/t.txt"に書き込み(コピー)をしようとしたなら、質問のようなエラーが起こると思います。
ファイルのパーミッションを確認してみてください。

"./t.txt"のパーミッションを書き込み可能に変更したら、同じエラーは起きなくなると思います。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。恥ずかしながら外部要因は盲点でした。
ただ、頂いたアドバイスに基づきパーミッションを確認してみた物の、読み取り専用はついておらず、
確認した限りファイルへのアクセス権にも問題はなさそうでした
(試しにアクセス権をEveryone&フルコントロールのみにしたり、chmod 777を適用させたり管理者権限で実行させたり等してみた物の、同様のエラーが発生してしまいました)